# Merging symbols in common lisp

Tags: merge, lisp, common-lisp, symbols

I want to insert a char into a list.  However, I want to merge this char with the last symbol in the list.  With appends and cons the result is always two different symbols.  Well, I want one merged symbol to be my result.

Example:

```
       (XXXX 'a '5) ====>  (a5)
```

What I would like to have, instead of:

```
       (XXXX 'a '5) ====> (a 5)
```

Answer (score 11):

You cannot "merge symbols" in Lisp.

First of all, `5` is not a symbol, but a number. If you want a symbol named `"5"` you have to type it as `|5|` (for example).

If a function takes the symbol `A` and symbol `|5|`, and produces the symbol `A5`, it has not merged symbols. It has created a new symbol whose name is the catenation of the names of those input symbols.

Properly designed Lisp programs rarely depend on how a symbol is named. They depend on symbols being unique entities.

If you're using symbols to identify things, and both `5` and `A` identify some entity, the best answer isn't necessarily to create a new symbol which is, in name at least, is a mashup of these two symbols. For instance, a better design might be to accept that names are multi-faceted or compound in some way. Perhaps the list `(A 5)` can serve as a name.

Common Lisp functions themselves can have compound names. For instance `(setf foo)` is a function name. Aggregates like lists can be names.

If you simply need the machine to invent unique symbols at run-time, consider using the `gensym` function. You can pass your own prefix to it:

```
(gensym "FOO") -> #:FOO0042
```

Of course, the prefix can be the name of some existing symbol, pulled out via `symbol-name`.  The symbol `#:FOO0042` is not unique because of the `0042` but because it is a freshly allocated object in the address space. The `#:` means it is not interned in any package. The name of the symbol is `FOO0042`.

If you still really want to, a simple way to take the printed representation of a bunch of input objects and turn it into a symbol is this:

```
(defun mashup-symbol (&rest objects)
  (intern (format nil "~{~a~}" objects)))
```

Examples:

```
(mashup-symbol 1 2 3) -> |123|

(mashup-symbol '(a b) 'c 3) -> |(A B)C3|
```

Answer (score 5):

Define this:

```
(defun symbol-append (&rest symbols) 
  (intern (apply #'concatenate 'string 
                 (mapcar #'symbol-name symbols))))
```

and then use it as:

```
* (symbol-append 'a 'b 'c)
ABC

* (apply #'symbol-append '(a b c))
ABC
```

If you expect your arguments to contain stuff besides symbols, then replace `symbol-name` with:

```
   (lambda (x)
     (typecase x ...))
```

or a pre-existing CL function (that I've forgotten :() that stringifies anything.

Comment: Function `string` stringifies what string designators, but not, say, pathnames

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question you ask is

```
(defun concatenate-objects-to-symbol (&rest objects)
  (intern (apply #'concatenate 'string (mapcar #'princ-to-string objects))))
(concatenate-objects 'a 'b) ==> ab
```

Oh, if you want a *list* as the result:

```
(defun xxxx (s1 s2) (list (concatenate-objects-to-symbol s1 s2)))
```

However, I am pretty sure this is *not* the question you actually *want* to ask.

Creating new symbols programmatically is not something beginners should be doing...

Comment: As soon as you enter a token into your Lisp listener, which is interpreted as a symbol name, you've created a symbol.

Comment: No fair! You copied my answer!! (define xxxx (s1 s2) ...) <smiley>