# In Common Lisp, what's the best way to write a macro that defines a class?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, symbols

I'm trying to write a macro in Common Lisp that defines a class with variant slots I specify. So far it's worked OK (and I've been very impressed with clisp!) for this:

```
(defmacro notifier (class slot) 
  "Defines a setf method in (class) for (slot) which calls the object's changed method."
   `(defmethod (setf ,slot) (val (item ,class))
     (setf (slot-value item ',slot) val)
     (changed item ',slot)))

(defmacro notifiers (class slots)
  "Defines setf methods in (class) for all of (slots) which call the object's changed method."
  `(progn 
     ,@(loop for s in slots collecting `(notifier ,class ,s))))

(defmacro defclass-notifier-slots (class nslots slots)
  "Defines a class with (nslots) giving a list of slots created with notifiers, and (slots) giving a list of slots created with regular accessors."
  `(progn
     (defclass ,class () 
       ( ,@(loop for s in nslots collecting `(,s :reader ,s)) 
         ,@(loop for s in slots collecting `(,s :accessor ,s))))
     (notifiers ,class ,nslots)))
```

The problem is, now I want to create not *just* the slots I specify in the call to the macro, but some other slots as well with variant names. In order to do that, I'd have to use an ugly "symbol-name, alter string, intern" sequence to generate the variant name as a slot name, and I've already seen answers on SO that say you should avoid doing that. So is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `"symbol-name, alter string, intern" sequence` is _the_ standard way. Please reference the posts which deprecate it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710108/merging-symbols-in-common-lisp

Comment: I don't see those answers deprecating symbol creation at macroexpand time. In fact, this is what `defclass` et al do!

Comment: So something like this is OK:
`(defun append-symbol (symbol appstr)
  (intern (concatenate 'string (symbol-name symbol) appstr)))`,
`(defmacro build-stat-pane (name statslist)
  (let ((pane-symbols 
     (loop for (n sname) in statslist collecting (list (append-symbol n "-title") (append-symbol n "-pane") sname)))) \`(define-interface ,name () () (:panes ,@(loop for (ti p n) in pane-symbols collecting \`(,ti title-pane :text ,n) collecting \`(,p display-pane))))))`

Comment: yes, fine (hard to read in a comment though)

Comment: @MarkGreen: make sure that you INTERN the new symbol in the right package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with constructing new symbols inside a macro or one of its helper functions.

Whenever you need something multiple times or you need to document it in some way, write a function.

Since we need to use a possibly new symbol, it makes sense to make sure the symbol is in the right package. Here we just assume the package of the *prefix* symbol is the right package.

```
(defun make-suffix-symbol (prefix suffix)
  (check-type prefix symbol)
  (check-type suffix (or string symbol))
  (when (symbolp suffix)
    (setf suffix (symbol-name suffix)))
  (intern (concatenate 'string
                       (symbol-name prefix)
                       suffix)
          (symbol-package prefix)))

CL-USER 12 > (make-suffix-symbol 'http-user::foo "BAR")
HTTP-USER::FOOBAR
```

or using `FORMAT`:

```
(defun make-suffix-symbol (prefix suffix &optional (format-string "~A~A"))
   (check-type prefix symbol)
   (check-type suffix (or string symbol))
   (when (symbolp suffix)
     (setf suffix (symbol-name suffix)))
   (intern (format nil
                   format-string
                   (symbol-name prefix)
                   suffix)
           (symbol-package prefix)))

CL-USER 14 > (make-suffix-symbol 'http-user::foo "BAR" "~a-~a")
HTTP-USER::FOO-BAR
```