# Merge symbols maintaining their case in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, symbols

In my code symbols must be case sensitive:

```
(eq 'p 'P)
nil
```

so I've added:

```
(setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :invert)
```

at the beginning of the file and It works very well.

But I also have to make a symbol out of two symbols (merge them)

```
(foo 'K 'm)
Km
```

to "merge" two symbols I've found the following function 
([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710108/merging-symbols-in-common-lisp)):

```
(defun symbol-append (&rest symbols) 
  (intern (apply #'concatenate 'string 
                 (mapcar #'symbol-name symbols))))
```

which works but doesn't maintain the case:

```
CL-USER> (symbol-append 'K 'm)
KM
```

How can I merge two symbols while maintaining the case?

**EDIT**

The '|some-symbol| did it BUT I had to set back

```
(setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :upcase)
```

So now in my "data base" I have stuff like |Km| or |PHz| which is fine.

Problem now is that the user of the program is going to insert stuff like `Km` or `PHz` that I want to compare to the ones in my db but:

```
(eq '|Km| 'Km)
nil
```

because `Km` is interned as `KM` and `|Km|` as `|Km|`.
Help plz.

Comment: It does maintain the case: `(symbol-append '|K| '|m|)` -> 
`|Km|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making some error, as:

```
> (setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :invert)
> (symbol-name (symbol-append 'K 'm))
"kM"
```

You will have a really exciting time trying to make this do the right thing (whatever the right thing is, which I really have no idea) when the case of your symbols is the opposite of what you've typed.  You could make `symbol-append` check for the readtable case, and diddle the case of the characters, but that's almost certainly going to happen at the wrong time.

What you quite likely want to do instead is distinguish between the language you are trying to write (where symbols are case-sensitive) and the CL code you are using to implement it.  Then write some reader for the language you are trying to write which may be as simple as binding `*readtable*` to a case-sensitive one (not with `:invert`, with `:preserve`).  Then the symbols you read will have the cases you expect.  This might be as simple as something like:

```
(defun make-case-preserving-readtable (&optional (from *readtable*))
  (let ((r (copy-readtable from)))
    (setf (readtable-case r) ':preserve)
    r))

(defparameter *case-preserving-readtable* (make-case-preserving-readtable))

(defmacro with-case-preserving-readtable (&body forms)
  `(let ((*readtable* *case-preserving-readtable*))
     ,@forms))
```

(This code tries to both copy anything useful about the current readtable and avoid consing a new one for each time the macro is used.

With this, for instance:

```
> (with-case-preserving-readtable
    (format t "~&in: ")
    (read))
in: (foo :bar 1 |FOO|)
(|foo| :|bar| 1 foo)
```

Comment: I don't understand why the macro won't work if called like this: `(with-case-preserving-readtable 'foo)` it returns `FOO`

Comment: @IDK: Because the form is read before it is evaluated: when the form is read, *including any forms nested within it*, the readtable is the ordinary one.  Only calls to `read` or functions which use it (say `load`) will be affected by it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CL-USER 34 > (eq 'km '|KM|)
T

CL-USER 35 > (eq 'km '|Km|)
NIL
```

Comparing two different symbols with different case for the names.

```
CL-USER 36 > (let ((a 'km)
                   (b '|Km|))
               (and (eql (symbol-package a)
                         (symbol-package b))
                    (string-equal a b)))
T
```